# Migration from framework 4.6.1 to 6 (LTS)

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, sqlclient

We started the migration of 40 projects from framework 4.6.1 to 6 and everything seems fine but I have one question.

We used the upgrade-assistant tool on a simple project; it works great but the `system.data` reference was removed so we have a lot of inline "errors" related to `DataSet/DataTable/DataRows/...` but also everything related to `SqlClient`.

We want to update the "old" `System.Data.SqlClient` to the new `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` (it seems a better long-term choice)

Two solutions:

- re-add the system.data and that's it, everything runs well.
- add the nuget package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (installed manually with the nupkg file as it doesn't appear in the nuget packet manager :|)

I suppose the best is the second option, so we add the Imports Microsoft.Data (or add the namespace in the project) as we referenced object with "SqlClient.SqlConnection", "SqlClient.SqlCommand", "SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter"

But the errors on DataSet/DataTable/DataRows/ stay there. So I suppose it's always necessary to add the System.Data namespace?

But how do we avoid errors like this (easily of course. Without all renames)

```
Error   BC37229 'SqlCommand' is ambiguous between declarations in namespaces 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, System.Data.SqlClient
```

Thanks

Comment: I used the first option. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The transition from .Net 4.6.1 to .Net 6 is a major jump and as you mentioned, using Nuget is how you would work with new libraries going forward since you no longer have the full .Net Framework Library in your app by default.

If you want to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient throughout your project you would add that reference via Nuget and add your using references via a global reference (if needed) or on your individual class files.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

[image]

I would ensure you are using the latest version of Visual Studio too.

Comment: OK thanks but it doesn't answer the orginal question of the same class using dataset (system.data) and sqlclient (system.data migrated to microsoft.data ...)

Answer (score 0):

The only place you need to change from *System.Data* to *Microsoft.Data* is on *OperationAbortedException*. In other cases System.Data is still a valid reference. You can look into the [Cheet-Sheet](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/main/porting-cheat-sheet.md) from SqlClient team.

Answer (score 0):

### The compilation issue

.NET 6 introduced "implicit using", so that you need to check if the project ends up with `System.Data` added in the implicit list (usually in `obj\Debug|Release\net6.0\projectName.GlobalUsings.g.cs`), or elsewhere in your source files.

Remove `System.Data` from there should stop BC37229.

### Who is the future?

Quoted from https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient,

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is a data provider for Microsoft SQL Server
> and Azure SQL Database. Now in General Availability, it is a union of
> the two System.Data.SqlClient components which live independently in
> .NET Framework and .NET Core. **Going forward, support for new SQL
> Server features will be implemented in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.**